# Martingale property of an stochastic integral, stopping time, stopping theorem

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

before asking my question regarding of the martingale property of the stochastic integral I want to define some of the notations in the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642318979) I'm following:

1. $\mathcal{M}^2$ is the set of continuous martingales $(M_t, t\in \mathbb{R}^{+} )$ in $L^2$ such that $M_0=0$.
2. For $M \in \mathcal{M}^2$, let $L^2(M)$ denote the set of progressively measurable processes $(H_s, s \in \mathbb{R}^{+} )$ such that: 
   $$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} H_s^2 d\langle M \rangle_t \right] < \infty $$

I would like to prove that, if $M, N \in \mathcal{M}^2$, $H \in L^2(M) $ and $K \in L^2(N)$, then for every finite stopping time $T$, we have:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^{T} H_s dM_s \right) \left( \int_0^{T} K_s dN_s \right)\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^{T} H_sK_s d\langle M,N \rangle_s \right]$$

My first approach was to prove that $L_t := (H \cdot M)_{t}(K \cdot N)_{t} - \langle H\cdot M,K \cdot N \rangle_t$ is a martingale $L^2$ (ie $L_t \in \mathcal{M}^2$) and so we can apply the stopping theorem and knowing that $L_0=0$ we would have proven the equality. It is not very clear that it is a martingale, but by definition of the quadratic variation, it is a local martingale. I don't know how to prove that $\mathbb{E} [L_t^2] < \infty$. I've tried with Kunita-Watanabe inequality but I don't find the right conditions that $L_t$ should verify for being able to apply the stopping theorem.

On the other hand, I've been thinking that given the stopping time $T$ is finite, then if $L_t$ is a martingale, the stopped martingale $L_t^T$ is bounded by the value of the martingale in $T$ so, $L_t^T \in \mathcal{M}^2$
and we would have the desired equality.

I'm not sure if my reasoning make sense, and if it possible to prove my first idea. Every help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this result holds, consider for example two independent one dimensional Brownian motions $B_s$ and $B'_s$. Their quadratic covariation is equal to zero at every timepoint, whilst $⟨B'⟩_s = ⟨B ⟩_s = s$, meaning the right side of your equation is always zero while the left side isn't necessarily.

Comment: I think it holds as it is an exercise on the notes that I'm following [Page 54, exercise 5.2.6]: https://www.lpsm.paris/pageperso/fournier/PolyCS.pdf   Also I think maybe your reasoning is not right because if the brownian motions are independent, then we can separate the expectation on the left side, and we would also get zero, as the expectation of the stochastic integral defined like that is zero.

Comment: Then one the left side it should be the integrals w.r.t. the processes themselves, not w.r.t. their quadratic variation

Comment: In this case you can show the result using remark 5.1.10 ii) of the document you linked in combination with the polarization identity applied the quadratic variation

Comment: You're absolutely right, I made a mistake on the writing, and already corrected it, thank you. Is that remark applicable in that case? as we don't have that $L_t := (H \cdot M)_{t}(K \cdot N)_{t} - \langle H\cdot M,K \cdot N \rangle_t$ is a martingale (or I don't know how to prove it), but a local martingale, and T is a stopping time.